# Somebody please tell me what details are lacking in this question

Tags: discussion

I asked this yesterday (and that was my second attempt, rewritten, after the first attempt was also closed for the same reason): [In Ocarina of Time and Majora's Mask, are the "follow-guy maze puzzle" routes randomly picked each time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372334/in-ocarina-of-time-and-majoras-mask-are-the-follow-guy-maze-puzzle-routes-ra)

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.

Same thing over and over again. I swear, if *my* questions are this frequently closed for nonsensical reasons (how is it unclear in *any* manner?), I can just *sense* the frustration from all the people who are *far* less careful than I and who write *much* worse questions, and thus must logically be closed/deleted all the time, every day.

I truly cannot see any possible reason that my question "needs details or clarity". It explains exactly what I'm asking, in the most clear manner possible. What's wrong? How is it unclear or lacking details?

It's almost as if the person who closed it did it because they aren't experts on those two (very related) games, which **actually have unique tags on here**. Only in that sense can it be considered "lacking details or clarity". Does he want me to describe the entire game from start to finish? I bet it would've been closed as "too vague" then...

No matter how careful I am, no matter how high-quality my questions are, they always get closed on this site. It's absurd and very discouraging and insulting. I'm sure you must be aware that it *is* taken personally to have one's time wasted like this; to have some unknown person click a button to close it with a seemingly randomly generated "reason".

Comment: As the user who initiated the close on the second question, I apologize for acting hastily on submitting the close vote :) Welcome to Arqade! I wish you have a much better experience in the days to come

Comment: You seem to be using a different account from the one you used to ask that linked question. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts on how to merge your two accounts.

Comment: I am simple user. I see two identical questions - I downvote both and vote-close one of them. You shouldn't be posting same question twice. I am maybe a bad guy to punish you, but I hope next time you will think twice before hitting submit buttons twice. Or better 3 times... I mean thinking. And nothing personal, it's all about your two posts. Btw, I removed downvote now.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, closing reasons are limited. Custom reasons can be entered, but users usually like to find the closing category most fitting the real reason.

Secondly, asking the same question again will cause annoyance with some users, who are likely less open to reconsidering your question's intent. Especially when it is done under different user names, which can easily be interpreted as a way to circumvent 'the system'.

That all being said, **I think the closing reason used was indeed very uninformative and probably wrongly used**. This also seems to be the opinion of other users, judging by the comments.

The problem *I* see with your [first question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372333/), is that **it seems to ask after the intention of the developers and/or the potential implementation of a gameplay mechanic**, [which are both off-topic here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
Your [second question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372334/) **can be considered too broad**, although you really just give multiple options as potential answers, and I see no problem with that.

(A side-note: it is up to the users seeing your question (in review queues or visiting the website) to judge the quality of it.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm the one that closed both of your questions.  I read your original, re-read it, and...I can't seem to figure out what you're asking.  It's a cross between describing how the game works and how you think the developers wanted it to work.  That's not a question.  There's no problem statement, nothing to latch on to solve.

The second question was better, it added some questions to answer.  But reposting a question isn't the way to go; editing your previous question is.  I should have closed the second as a duplicate of the first.  That was my mistake.  Since it does seem like you have attempted to resolve the issue, I reopened your linked question.

I note that all three posts (this one, and both questions on main) are using different accounts.  This is going to cause problems when you need to fix something on one of your questions, or respond to requests for clarification.  It doesn't help when a brand new account re-asks a question after the original gets closed; it looks like an attempt to get around the site moderation, and that's pretty frowned upon.  If you can use one account and stick with it, it'll be better for everyone.